# What is a UITapAndAHalfRecognizer?

Tags: objective-c, uitextview, uigesturerecognizer, gesture-recognition, uitapgesturerecognizer

I notice that when I cycle through the gesture recognizers of a `UITextView` and output the description of each to the console, one of the recognizers that seemed utterly curious was the `UITapAndAHalfRecognizer`. I know about the others such as `UITextTapRecognizer` but this one really piqued my interest. Does anyone know what gestures this recognizer handles? How can you have half a tap? Is that a tap and then a press and hold?

Comment: http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/UIGestureRecognizer#UITapAndAHalfRecognizer

Comment: Nice find Ethan. I know it's a "link" answer but if you want to put it as an answer instead of a comment with constructive explanation for other users that stumble upon this thread, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know for certain, but I suspect that it's for a tap followed closely by a press (first half of a tap).

As per [Ethan Holshouser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/969961/ethan-holshouser)'
s comment, see also: http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/UIGestureRecognizer#UITapAndAHalfRecognizer

Comment: I wonder why they don't make that a visible class to developers